Can you solve this visual matrix style puzzle with layers of colored arcs?
Here is a visual puzzle I have created.
Pick the 2 images that correspond to the question marks below (the order of your choices matter).



The answer is:

 7, 3

Explanation:

 The following steps are applied to go from a figure to the one on its right: rotate the blue parts 90 degrees clockwise, make the blue parts "fall" inside the black ring if they cross a hole, and rotate the red parts 90 degrees counterclockwise. Purple represents blue and red overlapping.

